# ¿Cómo sustituir las columnas de los extremos de una dataframe por los valores de una tabla en una columna de otra dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframe. `data`: una con preguntas en la columna `Questions`

```
    Questions   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   1   2   3   4   5
43  Were you financially impacted due to the COVID...   1   2   3   4   5
58  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   1   2   3   4   5
60  5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pa...   0   1   2   3   4
```

Y otro, `df_meaning` con las mismas preguntas en la columna `Questions`, las escalas en una primera tabla de la columna `Answers` y lo que significa las extremidades de estas escalas en una segunda tabla:

```
Questions   Answers
4   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?   [None, 5, [[61960967, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['10']], 0, ['Not preferred', 'Preferred']]]]
79  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what extent has your income been affected?  [None, 5, [[1214291070, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['10']], 0, ['Low affected', 'High affected']]]]
81  5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pandemic affected your mental health?   [None, 5, [[735213491, [['0'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5']], 0, ['Not affected', 'Extremely affected']]]]
```

Por ejemplo `['Not affected', 'Extremely affected']` da la significacion de la scala `0 1 2 3 4 5` de la pregunta `5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pandemic affected your mental health?`

Me gustaría remplazar las primeras y ultimas columnas `Answeri` de `data` con las extremidades de la segunda tabla. Es por decir obtener una cosa como:

```
    Questions   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   'Not preferred'     2   3   4   'Preferred'
58  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   'Low affected'  2   3   'High affected'
```

Sé cómo coincidir en las preguntas:

```
import ast # no preocupe, todo es string en mi propia lista
for _, row in data.iterrows():
    for i, row_meaning in df_meaning.iterrows():
        if row.Questions == row.Questions:
            # tomamos la última tabla de la matriz de tablas (3 veces anidada) de la columna de respuestas de df_meaning
            full_l = ast.literal_eval(row_meaning.Answers)
            l = full_l[-1][-1][-1]
            # sustituir la primera columna Pregunta0 por el primer elemento de la tabla y la última columna que no es Ninguna por el último elemento de la tabla.
            break
```

## Actualizacion

La respuesta de DannyTalent casi resolve el problema. De hecho, las respuestas se ponen en la columna de la izquierda pero no en la derecha, o se ponen todas en la ultima columna, que  pueden ver [aqui](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HkjwgMxp5i_URalgz8w5YswniNMfPX2S6UZ0QUoka8/edit?usp=sharing).

Dado que solo doy estracto en las dataframes arriba, tuve que adaptar el código:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(data, df_meaning, on="Questions")
def get_rpta(row, num):
    if row.QType_x == 'Likert Scale':
        try:
            lista_work = ast.literal_eval(row["Answers_y"])[2][0][3]  # Obtener la parte necesaria de Answers
            if num==0:
                ans_index = 0
            else:
                ans_index = 1
            print(lista_work)
            return lista_work[ans_index]
        except TypeError:
            pass
        except IndexError:
            return row.Answer0
    else: return row.Answer0

df_merged["Answer0"] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_rpta(x, 0), axis=1)
lista_cols = [x for x in df_merged.columns if x.lower().startswith("answer") and x not in ["Answers","Answers_x","Answers_y"]] # Lista de las columnas AnswerX
last_ans = max([int(x[6:]) for x in lista_cols])
df_merged[f"Answer{last_ans}"] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_rpta(x, 1), axis=1)
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu lógica para asignar las respuestas. Cómo pasas de 5 a "Preferred", por ejemplo, en "Answer4" ??? Todo lo demás te entendí y elaboré una respuesta, pero me falta eso jaja, la estructura no ayuda mucho...

Comment: @DannyTalent Muchas gracias por su comentario. He actualizado la pregunta. Basicamente tomamos la última tabla de la matriz de tablas (3 veces anidada) de la columna `Answers` de df_meaning. Sustituimos la primera columna Pregunta0 por el primer elemento de esta tabla. y la última columna que no es `None` por el último elemento de la tabla. En realidad hay mucho mas columnas que estas. ¿Está más claro?

Comment: en tu error sale que no existe la clave "Answers", quizás no se llama así en tu dataframe real? Yo copié la info tal cual la pusiste en la pregunta y no me da error... O quizás data tiene otra columna "Answers", en cuyo caso el merge creará la columna "Answers_x" que corresponde a la de `data` y "Answers_y", que corresponde a `df_meaning`

Comment: @DannyTalent si, eso es: tengo `Answers_x` y `Answers_y`. ¿Puedo usar cualquiera de estos indistintamente?

Comment: Si ya tienes la columna `Answers` en el dataframe original, creo que ya no necesitarías hacer el merge, y ambas columnas serían lo mismo. El merge era para reemplazar tus `iterrows()`, nada más!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yendo por partes...

### **1. Hacer coincidir dataframes con `iterrows()` es la forma incorrecta de usar pandas**

Suele ser bastante lento, y puede ser reemplazado en una sola línea:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(data, df_meaning, on="Questions")
```

Este dataframe nuevo te devuelve:

```
                                           Questions  Answer0  Answer1  Answer2  Answer3  Answer4                                            Answers
0  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...        1        2        3        4        5  [None, 5, [[61960967, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['...
1  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...        1        2        3        4        5  [None, 5, [[1214291070, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ...
2  5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pa...        0        1        2        3        4  [None, 5, [[735213491, [['0'], ['1'], ['2'], [...
```

Es decir, funciona como un `inner join` (solo aparecen coincidencias), si quieres mantener los registros de `data` aunque no hayan respuestas en `df_meaning`, simplemente añades el arg `how="left"` (o right, si quieres hacer que `df_meaning` sea el que determina cuál fila queda o no:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(data, df_meaning, how="left", on="Questions")
```

Esto devuelve

```
                                           Questions  Answer0  Answer1  Answer2  Answer3  Answer4                                            Answers
0  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...        1        2        3        4        5  [None, 5, [[61960967, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['...
1  Were you financially impacted due to the COVID...        1        2        3        4        5                                                NaN
2  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...        1        2        3        4        5  [None, 5, [[1214291070, [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ...
3  5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pa...        0        1        2        3        4  [None, 5, [[735213491, [['0'], ['1'], ['2'], [...
```

### **2. Accediendo a la respuesta**

He notado que pandas no "entiende" que tu columna *Answers* tiene forma de `list`, es decir, si yo hago `print(df_merged["Answers"][0])`, obtengo un objeto `str`.

Convertirlo en lista es muy fácil, solo hay que importar el módulo `ast` para hacer una evaluación literal, y luego se puede acceder al resto de índices, por ejemplo para el primer registro (indice [0]):

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(df_merged["Answers"][0])[2][0][3])
```

Esto imprime:

```
['Not preferred', 'Preferred']
```

### **3. Se hace la selección del texto y columna**

Para hacer el match con la respuesta deseada usamos `df.apply()` y una función:

```
def get_rpta(row, num):
    lista_work = ast.literal_eval(row["Answers"])[2][0][3]  # Obtener la parte necesaria de Answers
    if num==0:
        ans_index = 0
    else:
        ans_index = 1
    return lista_work[ans_index]


df_merged["Answer0"] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_rpta(x, 0), axis=1)
```

Como verás, añadí el parámetro `num` para que la función sepa si necesitamos el primer dato o el último (0 si es el primero, cualquier otra cosa si es el último).

Ahora, para sacar la última respuesta, solo se requiere saber cuál es la última columna y aplicar la misma función:

```
lista_cols = [x for x in df_merged.columns if x.lower().startswith("answer") and x != "Answers"] # Lista de las columnas AnswerX
last_ans = max([int(x[6:]) for x in lista_cols])
df_merged[f"Answer{last_ans}"] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: get_rpta(x, 1), axis=1)
```

Finalmente, podemos eliminar la columna Answers, que ya no necesitamos, e imprimir el dataframe.

```
del df_merged["Answers"]
print(df_merged)
```

### Resultado final

```
                                           Questions        Answer0  Answer1  Answer2  Answer3             Answer4
0  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...  Not preferred        2        3        4           Preferred
1  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   Low affected        2        3        4       High affected
2  5 - On a scale of 0-5, how has the covid-19 pa...   Not affected        1        2        3  Extremely affected
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu brillante respuesta! Casi hizo lo que quería hacer en el marco de datos total. De hecho, las respuestas se ponen en la columna de la izquierda pero no en la derecha, o se ponen todas en la ultima columna como se puede ver [aquí](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HkjwgMxp5i_URalgz8w5YswniNMfPX2S6UZ0QUoka8/edit?usp=sharing). ¿Sabría cómo arreglar este problema?

Comment: Voy a actualizar mi pregunta como adapté tu respuesta. He publicado una nueva pregunta [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372449/c%c3%b3mo-muevo-el-texto-de-la-celda-al-final-de-una-l%c3%adnea-casi-completamente-vac%c3%ada?noredirect=1#comment668296_372449)