# ¿Cómo muevo el texto de la celda al final de una línea casi completamente vacía al primer elemento que no está vacío en el otro extremo?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo [un google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-HkjwgMxp5i_URalgz8w5YswniNMfPX2S6UZ0QUoka8/edit?usp=sharing) donde ciertas respuestas no estan en el lugar correcto.

En efecto, me gustaría que, para cada línea, dada la respuesta en la última columna, si la respuesta no está ya en una columna Answeri, movamos esta respuesta a la izquierda en la primera columna que no es ninguna.

Es por decir obtener una cosa como:

```
    Questions   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4
3   What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...   'Not preferred'     2   3   4   'Preferred'
58  3 - If yes, on a scale of 0 -10, to what exten...   'Low affected'  2   3   'High affected'
```

Hasta ahora he escrito esto:

```
import pandas as pd

def put_at_right_place(row):
    if row.Answer257 != None:
        answer = row.Answer257
        for i in range(0,257):
            if row[Answer + str(i)]!= None
                index_to_replace = i
            if answer not in row[Answer + str(i)]:
                # on choppe la premiere colonne qui n'est pas None
                row(i) = row.Answer257

df = pd.read_csv('la_hoja_del_vinclulo.csv')
df["Answer" + ?] = df.apply(lambda x: put_at_right_place(x), axis=1) # ? porque no sé cual es el index que me interessa
```

Como está en las hojas de Google, estaré muy contento de intentarlo con el Editor de script javascript tambien.

## Actualizacion

Intenté la resupesta de DannyTalent pero obtengo, con la dataframe descargada del vinculo, una `ValueError`:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3063: DtypeWarning: Columns (37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-848-c128dd25f69f> in <module>
      2 # df_merged = df_merged.drop('Answers_x', 'Answers_y', 'QType_y')
      3 df_merged = pd.read_csv('merged_2.csv')
----> 4 df_merged = df_change_last_column(df_merged)

<ipython-input-842-b61804abaeff> in df_change_last_column(dataframe)
      1 def df_change_last_column(dataframe):
----> 2     lista_cols = [int(x[6:]) for x in dataframe.columns if x.lower().startswith("answer") and not x.lower().startswith("Answers")] # Lista de las columnas AnswerX, sale [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]
      3     max_col = max(lista_cols) # ultima columna
      4     def find_last_col(row):
      5         for col in lista_cols:

<ipython-input-842-b61804abaeff> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 def df_change_last_column(dataframe):
----> 2     lista_cols = [int(x[6:]) for x in dataframe.columns if x.lower().startswith("answer") and not x.lower().startswith("Answers")] # Lista de las columnas AnswerX, sale [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]
      3     max_col = max(lista_cols) # ultima columna
      4     def find_last_col(row):
      5         for col in lista_cols:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'
```

Como si siguiera teniendo en cuenta la columna de respuestas `Answers` a pesar de  `not x.lower().startswith("Answers")`

Comment: ¿En cuales líneas del `sheet` que señalas se produce el problema en cuestión?

Comment: Todos menos los pocos que llegan a la última columna.

Comment: O sea, ¿mover las respuestas en columna "Answer257" hacia la izquierda?

Comment: @CandidMoe Exactamente

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir los imports y el resto del código, cosa que sea cortar y pegar en nuestra IDE. Revisa está página sobre [Como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Entiendo, quieres que ponga la respuesta en la última columna que no tiene un valor vacío, no en la última columna de la hoja correcto?

Comment: @DannyTalent si! Exactamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo! Reciclé un poco de código de la anterior pregunta, pero creo que los comentarios ayudan a entender qué está pasando.

```
def df_change_last_column(dataframe):
    lista_cols = [int(x[6:]) for x in dataframe.columns if x.lower().startswith("answer") and not x.lower().startswith("answers")] # Lista de las columnas AnswerX, sale [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]
    max_col = max(lista_cols) # ultima columna
    def find_last_col(row):
        for col in lista_cols:
            if pd.notna(row[f"Answer{col}"]): # si la columna col no es nula, continuar a la siguiente
                continue
            if col-1 <= 0:
                continue
            row[f"Answer{col-1}"] = row[f"Answer{max_col}"] # si es null, asignar el valor de la columna maxima a la anterior
            row[f"Answer{max_col}"] = np.NaN # El ultimo ahora es NaN
            break
        return row
    dataframe = dataframe.apply(lambda x: find_last_col(x), axis=1)
    return dataframe
```

Básicamente, lo que hago es iterar por cada fila por todas las columnas del dataframe que comiencen con "Answer", (0, 1, 2, 3...) hasta que encuentre un valor nulo. De encontrarlo, significa que el Answer anterior (Answer(X-1)) es el último valor no-nulo, por lo que hacemos el swap con la última Answer.

Finalmente, para ejecutar la función, es algo tan simple como llamar:

```
df = df_change_last_column(df)
```

### Limitaciones

El único problema que se me ocurre que puede pasar es si la escala tiene (answermaxima - 1) valores solamente, ya que el penúltimo answer sería el que debe ser reemplazado (no encuentra ningún NaN), pero creo que se puede arreglar con un condicional... O simplemente combinas esta función con la que hace que Answer257 tenga su valor, para no tener que intercambiar los valores en primer lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias para tu respuesta, sin embargo obtengo un ValueError con la dataframe en elvinculo: parece que siguiera teniendo en cuenta la columna de respuestas `Answers` a pesar de  `not x.lower().startswith("Answers")`

Comment: Si!!! Disculpa, cambia "Answers" por "answers", olvidé que le había puesto `lower()`

Comment: Si, funciona! Sin embargo crea una columna de `Answer-1` donde puesta cosas que supongo deberian ser en `Answer1` (y creo que desordena las columnas).

Comment: Encontré el bug! Parece que algunas `Answer0` están vacías, y te crea `Answer-1`, adicionalmente vi que a veces elimina la columna `Answer0` cuando no debería, ya modifiqué el código (solo es un if), mira qué tal

Answer (score 1):

Conozco bien poco de pandas, asi que tome esto como un ejercicio para agarrarle el asunto. Debe haber formas más elegantes de hacerlo ...

Las celdas que no traen valores en la planilla original aparecen como NaN en el DataFrame.

Construí esta función auxiliar para comprobar si la celda está vacía.

```
def is_empty(value):
    """ Evalúa el valor para detectar NaN
    
    @param value: un item arbitrario (entero, flotante, string, NaN)
    @return True si value == NaN
    """
    return type(value) is float and math.isnan(value)
```

Ahora se trata de recorrer la fila para intercambiar los elementos:

```
def ajusta_fila(row):
    """ Ajusta una fila del dataframe, moviendo la ultima celda.
    
    @param row: Una fila
    @return: La fila con el ultimo elemento puesto a la cola de
    los primeros.
    """
    if not is_empty(row[-1]):
        ''' Hay algo en la ultima columna de la fila '''
        desp = -2
        while is_empty(row[desp]):
            ''' Retroceder por la fila buscando primer no NaN '''
            desp -= 1
        ''' Movernos a la derecha, primera celda NaN '''
        desp += 1
        ''' Intercambiar ultima celda con primera celda vacia '''
        row[-1], row[desp] = row[desp], row[-1]
```

**Comprobación**

Hice este programa para listar la conversión de las 10 primeras filas.

Por cada fila, imprimi primero el valor original en la ultima celda, para chequear que haya un valor y que luego sea efectivamente traspasado.

Luego imprimi las celdas convertidas anteponiendo el número de celda entre "[]", y asi revisar la columna en que quedan los datos.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.read_csv("/home/candid/PycharmProjects/pandas/archivo.csv", dtype=str)
        
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index > 10:
        break
    print("Ultimo valor de entrada: ", row[-1])
    ajusta_fila(row)
    index_col = 1
    for value in row:
        if not is_empty(value):
            print("[%4d] " % index_col, value, end=", ")
        index_col += 1
    print()
    print()
```

lo que produce:

```
Ultimo valor de entrada:  In next 3 months
[   1]  1, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  When do you think your next vacation can start?, [   4]  ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed'], [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['think', 'vacat', 'start'], [   9]  In next 3 months, [  10]  In next 6 months, [  11]  In next 1 year, [  12]  Only once COVID-19 is under control, [  13]  Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed, [  14]  In next 3 months, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Doctor's availability in hotel
[   1]  2, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?, [   4]  ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care'], [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'medic', 'treatment', 'polici', 'addit', 'cost'], [   9]  Doctor's availability in hotel, [  10]  Ventilator availability in hotel, [  11]  Tie-ups with nearby hospitals, [  12]  Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care, [  13]  Doctor's availability in hotel, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Buffet breakfast with social distancing
[   1]  3, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?, [   4]  ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only'], [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'complementari', 'breakfast'], [   9]  Buffet breakfast with social distancing, [  10]  Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options, [  11]  Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable), [  12]  Packaged breakfast only, [  13]  Buffet breakfast with social distancing, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Preferred
[   1]  4, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?, [   4]  ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], [   6]  Likert Scale, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'hotel', 'groceri', 'shop', 'basic', 'necess', 'item', 'packag', 'food'], [   9]  Not preferred, [  10]  2, [  11]  3, [  12]  4, [  13]  5, [  14]  6, [  15]  7, [  16]  8, [  17]  9, [  18]  10, [  19]  Preferred, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing
[   1]  6, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of hotel check-in?, [   4]  ['Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code', 'Online Keys using the mobile App'], [   5]  Consumer Personality, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'hotel', 'check'], [   9]  Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing, [  10]  Collect keys at the KIOSK using booking bar-code, [  11]  Online Keys using the mobile App, [  12]  Collect keys at the counter maintaining social distancing, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing
[   1]  7, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of payment during Check-out?, [   4]  ['Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing', 'Pay at KIOSK', 'Online payment using the mobile App'], [   5]  Consumer Personality, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'payment', 'check'], [   9]  Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing, [  10]  Pay at KIOSK, [  11]  Online payment using the mobile App, [  12]  Pay at the counter maintaining social distancing, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Travel date change is preferred at no cost
[   1]  8, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of hotel cancellation / travel date change policy?, [   4]  ['Travel date change is preferred at no cost', 'Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy)', 'Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit'], [   5]  Consumer Personality, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'hotel', 'cancel', 'travel', 'date', 'chang', 'polici'], [   9]  Travel date change is preferred at no cost, [  10]  Cancellation at some minimal cost (based on hotel policy), [  11]  Cancellation with some amount refund and hotel coupons for next visit, [  12]  Travel date change is preferred at no cost, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Guests are allowed in living room with precautions
[   1]  9, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of the guest policy?, [   4]  ['Guests are allowed in living room with precautions', 'Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas', 'No guests are allowed inside hotel'], [   5]  Consumer Personality, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'guest', 'polici'], [   9]  Guests are allowed in living room with precautions, [  10]  Guest are allowed only in certain designated areas, [  11]  No guests are allowed inside hotel, [  12]  Guests are allowed in living room with precautions, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Regular concierge services
[   1]  10, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of the concierge service?, [   4]  ['Regular concierge services', 'Online concierge service'], [   5]  Consumer Personality, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'concierg', 'servic'], [   9]  Regular concierge services, [  10]  Online concierge service, [  11]  Regular concierge services, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Hand sanitizer
[   1]  12, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What are the items you feel are essential in your room?, [   4]  ['Hand sanitizer', 'Face mask', 'Face sheild', 'Hand gloves', 'Personal thermometers', 'Phone sanitizer', '', 1], [   5]  Consumer Intentions, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['item', 'feel', 'essenti', 'room'], [   9]  Hand sanitizer, [  10]  Face mask, [  11]  Face sheild, [  12]  Hand gloves, [  13]  Personal thermometers, [  14]  Phone sanitizer, [  15]  Hand sanitizer, 

Ultimo valor de entrada:  Other people can be present maintaining social distancing
[   1]  13, [   2]  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MYSjxAMCXMXB02GPXqkewVx35_ptzv0XO7GRZQGwyGE/edit?usp=sharing, [   3]  What is your preference of using the Spa/Sauna room?, [   4]  ['Other people can be present maintaining social distancing', 'Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available)', 'I will not prefer Spa/Sauna at all'], [   5]  Consumer Intentions, [   6]  Multiple Choice, [   7]  Hotel ABC, [   8]  ['prefer', 'sauna', 'room'], [   9]  Other people can be present maintaining social distancing, [  10]  Individual usage based on time sharing (Not all time slots will be available), [  11]  I will not prefer Spa/Sauna at all, [  12]  Other people can be present maintaining social distancing,
```